Installing PyQt6 gives me an error message
When I went into Windows PowerShell and ran pip install PyQt6, it gave me this error: DEPRECATION: Loading egg at c:\program files\python312\lib\site-packages\vboxapi-1.0-py3.12.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation.. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
Since that didn't work, I installed the latest version of PyQt6 with the installer from PyPI. That didn't work either, but it also didn't give me an error message.
Is there a way that I can fix this?
EDIT: I forgot to mention that I checked the discussion on GitHub.

Just see the link given, and the discussion on GitHub will tell you. Basically, pip dropped support for all .egg distributions. The best way to fix the problem is to upgrade pip, then uninstall all original .egg packages, and reinstall them.

I visited that link, but all of the comments in the discussion were about more issues with pip. I'll try this, then.
EDIT: It turns out that I am blind. The solution was in the discussion as you said.

@Mr.Mole So did that solve your problem?
